# If $ Y=Z_{1}+Z_{2} $ then $ \mathbb{E}[Y|X]=\mathbb{E}[Z_{1}|X]+\mathbb{E}[Z_{2}|X] $?

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

Assume $Y,X,Z_1,Z_2 $ are random variables, and assume that they all continuous and have density function, such that $Y=Z_1+Z_2$.

Can it be that $ \mathbb{E}[Y|X]=\mathbb{E}[Z_{1}|X]+\mathbb{E}[Z_{2}|X] $?

(Where $Y|X$ is the random variable whom density is $ f_{Y|X}\left(y,x\right):=\frac{f_{Y,X}\left(y,x\right)}{f_{X}\left(x\right)}$)

For me it seems very unlikely to be true, since conditioning is not a linear operation. But I cannot find a counter example nor prove equality.

I'd really appreciate a counter example/proof for this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1) $Y\mid X$ is not a r.v. 2) If $Y=Z_1+Z_2$, then indeed $\mathbb E[Y\mid X]=\mathbb E[Z_1\mid X]+\mathbb E[Z_2\mid X]$. But if $Y\neq Z_1+Z_2$, there is no reason for this formula to be true. Why do you think it could be ?

Comment: @Surb What do you mean its not a random variable? I explicitly wrote its density.

Comment: How would you define the random variable $Y\mid X$ ?

Comment: @Surb The random variable who have density $ f_{Y|X}\left(y,x\right):=\frac{f_{Y,X}\left(y,x\right)}{f_{X}\left(x\right)} $ (ofcourse it depends on $x $ and in some books the notation is $ Y|\left(X=x\right) $. I thought its a well known convention

Comment: This is not how things work. Infinitely many random variable can have the same density, therefore you can't define a random variable from a given density.

Comment: Moreover, $\mathbb E[Y\mid X]$ is not a number but a (a priori) non deterministic random variable, which contradict the fact that $Y\mid X$ would be a random variable.

Comment: @Surb if $Y|X $ is not a random variable then what exactly is $\mathbb{E}[Y|X] $ when expectation is an operator that accepts random variables as an operand?

Comment: $W:=\mathbb E[Y\mid X]$ is the unique $\sigma (X)-$measurable random variable s.t. $\mathbb E[UX]=\mathbb E[UW]$ for all r.v. $U$ being bounded and $\sigma (X)-$measurable.

Comment: @Surb I was sure that $ Y|X_{=x} $ is indeed a random variable, but ok. Good to know.  So why would $ Y=Z_{1}+Z_{2} $ imply $ \mathbb{E}[Y|X]=\mathbb{E}[Z_{1}|X]+\mathbb{E}[Z_{2}|X]$? (I thought that $Y|X$ is also a random varialbe and that $Y=Z_1+Z_2 $ does not imply $ Y|X = Y|Z_{1}+Y|Z_{2} $, But since , apparantly $Y|X $ is not a random varialbe there is no meaning, I guess, for the equality $ Y|X\neq Y|Z_{1}+Y|Z_{2} $)

Comment: If $Y$ is a random variable and $A$ is an event, then $Y \mid A$ is a random variable. Therefore for any $x$, $Y \mid X=x$ is a random variable. Therefore for any $x$, $\mathbb E[Y \mid X=x]$ is a number that depends on $x$; we can write a function $f$ such that $\mathbb E[Y \mid X=x] = f(x)$. Then $\mathbb E[Y \mid X]$ is defined to be the random variable $f(X)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $U\mapsto \mathbb E[U\mid X],$ is linear. To prove it, you have to prove that $$\mathbb E\big[\mathbb E[\alpha A+\beta B\mid X]V\big]=\mathbb E\big[(\alpha \mathbb E[A\mid X]+\beta \mathbb E[B\mid X])V\big],$$
for all $V$ being bounded and $\sigma (X)-$measurable, all $\alpha ,\beta \in \mathbb R$ and all bounded r.v. $A$ and $B$. But this is clear since if $V$ is bounded and $\sigma (X)-$measurable, $A$ and $B$ are bounded r.v. and $\alpha ,\beta \in \mathbb R$, then

\begin{align*}
\mathbb E\big[\mathbb E[\alpha A+\beta B\mid X ]V\big]&=\mathbb E[(\alpha A+\beta B)V]\\
&=\alpha \mathbb E[AV]+\beta \mathbb E[BV]\\
&=\alpha \mathbb E\big[\mathbb E[A\mid X]V \big]+\beta \mathbb E\big[\mathbb E[B\mid X]V\big]\\
&=\mathbb E\big[(\alpha \mathbb E[A\mid X]+\beta \mathbb E[B\mid X])V\big],
\end{align*}
what prove the claim.